# First order characterization of strict convexity

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I'm trying to show that if a function is strictly convex

$$f(y + \lambda(y-x))< f(y) + \lambda(f(y)-f(x)) $$

then

$$f(y) > f(x) + \nabla f(x)'(y-x) $$

without appealing to the Hessian.

With regular convexity I was able to do this by passing to a limit, where you get a situation like

$$f(x) - f(y) \ge \frac{f(y + \lambda(x-y)) - f(y)}{\lambda}$$

but if I replace the $\ge $ with $>$ the strict inequality might not survive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $f(y) = f(x) + \langle \nabla f(x), (y-x) \rangle$ for some $x \neq y$.

Let $\phi(t) = f(x+t(y-x))-f(x)-t \langle \nabla f(x), (y-x) \rangle$. The above can be written as $\phi(1) = \phi(0)$ and
we note that $\phi'(0) = 0$, so we have $\phi(t) = \phi(0)$ for all $t \in [0,1]$,
which contradicts $\phi$ being
strictly convex.

Hence $f(y) > f(x) + \langle \nabla f(x), (y-x) \rangle$ for all $x \neq y$.

Comment: " we note that ϕ′(0)=0, so we have ϕ(t)=ϕ(0) for all t∈[0,1], which contradicts ϕ being strictly convex."

Can you please elaborate why that's true and why ϕ not being strictly convex is enough to claim f isn't either?

Comment: @badmax: I can't because I had a mistake :-). I have fixed the mistake (I was missing $-f(x)$ in the formula. Think of Rolle's theorem.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: Wasn't me, although I am still not sure how $\phi(t) = \phi(0) \forall t$ based on the derivative at one point.

Comment: @badmax: If $\phi'(0) = 0$, and $\phi$ is convex, then $t=0$ is a minimiser of $\phi$ because we have $\phi(t) \ge \phi(0) + \phi'(0) t = \phi(0)$.